# Interpolating/estimating f on subset of integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, interpolation

Here is the question I have been struggling to solve lately. Imagine we have two integers $x, y \in \mathbb Z, x \le y$ and $Y = \{ a | a \in \mathbb Z\ and\ x \le a \le y \}$; $X\subset Y$. In the context of this specific question think of $|Y| \approx 10000$.

We want to find function $f: Y \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that, $f(x) = 1 \iff x \in X$.

Now the worst I can do is basically do the interpolation which will grow quite fast. I think we could do better using the fact that this function has to be only defined on integers, not on real line. I want to find $f$ that is cheap to compute (preferably bitwise operations).

Obviously it very much depends on the nature of the $Y$. For example, if the set contains only odd/even integers then finding $f$ becomes trivial. How would I generally approach this problem? I thought about decomposing the set into arithmetic progressions and then checking for each of them, but that does not seem to be very promising approach.

Comment: Let the binary number $Q$ have a 1 for its $r$th bit if $r$ is in $X$, else a zero. Then $f(z)$ is the $z$th bit of $Q$.

Comment: Storing $|Y|$ bits is not really feasible

Comment: That depends on how big $Y$ is. So maybe you have some considerations in mind that you have not made explicit in your question, and maybe you should work out what they are and edit them into the question.

Comment: Good point, I edited question!

Comment: 10,000 bits doesn't seem like a lot to me. I'm surprised storing that many bits isn't feasible.

Comment: It's not problematic to store that many bits, but fetching taht many bits is very inefficient as compared to evaluating function. Memory is really the slowest part of the modern computer, by huge margin too.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are asking for a search routine.
They are not very cheap.
For repeated searches, pay the overhead of sorting X.

Yes, if X has a nonrandom structure such as even numbers only,
that structure can be taken advantage of for a quick search.

Being a factor of seven wouldn't be as quick.
Will your data be structure so a program could be written
that would be cheaper than a general search routine?

Comment: In my case the set $X$ is fixed, but with no obvious pattern. Yes one idea that works fine is having basically precomputed truth table for each $x \in Y$, but memory is quite expensive resource (fetching memory is much slower than calculating bitwise operations), so I wanted to encode that information somehow in function, as evaluation of this function is much cheaper.